# PDF to EPS conversion: Bounding box problem

Tags: pdf, conversion, eps

PLOS journals require submission of EPS format figures instead of PDF.  Most of my figures were made in PDF and I used to simply crop the excess margins and use pdflatex to process the final output.

Now I am forced to use latex instead of pdflatex and had to convert my figures from PDF to EPS.  What is the best way of achieving this?  Can I crop the margins after EPS is created?  Alternatively can I crop the margins in PDF then convert it to EPS?  Which one will produce a lossless result?

Comment: `pdfcrop` followed by `pdftops` might help you.

Comment: If you have Inkscape you can simply use the terminal and type `inkscape foo.pdf -D --export-eps foo.eps`. If you use Linux you can do a loop. Search for loop in bash.

Comment: @Marienplatz I noticed that pdfcrop doesn't have options for customizing the bounding box.  It just crops to dimensions it thinks are correct.

-Sigur I would like to try inkscape, but I see that installing it on OSX Mtn Lion isn't so easy.  Especially given the fact that X11 isn't supported now.  Any workaround?